# Capybara redirecting to JSON response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec, capybara

I've got a form in my rails application that sends data remotely to a controller action. There is then JavaScript that waits on a successful AJAX response and then updates segments of the page.

When testing with Turnip, Rspec and Capybara, the `current_page` is redirected to the JSON response instead of staying on the page like I expect.

Here is some of the code:

**The controller action being hit**

```
def update
  @conversation.update(conversation_params)
  @conversation.save
  render json: @conversation, serializer: ConversationSerializer
end
```

**The form**

```
= simple_form_for(convo, remote: true, method: :json) do |f|
  - f.fields_for :messages, Message.new(conversation: f.object) do |msg|
    = msg.input :text, label: 'Message'
    = msg.submit 'Post Message', id: 'message-submit'
```

**The Coffeescript listening for success**

```
$(document).on 'ajax:success', 'form[data-remote]', (xhr, data, status) ->
  new_message_id = data.conversation.conversation_messages.pop().id

  $.get '/conversation_messages/'+new_message_id+'/partial', (data) ->
    $('#conversation .message').last().after(data)

$(document).on 'ajax:success', 'a[data-remote]', (xhr, data, status) ->
  location.reload()

$(document).on 'ajax:success', 'form[data-remote]', (xhr, data, status) ->
  location.reload()
```

**The test that is showing the wrong content**

```
step 'I say :message' do |message|
  fill_in 'Message', with: message
  click_on 'Post Message'
end

step 'I see the conversation message :message from :username' do |message, username|
  expect(page).to have_selector('.conversation-message-sender', text: username)
  expect(page).to have_selector('.conversation-message-text', text: message)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using a JavaScript capable driver for ajax submissions to work - see https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers

Comment: Thanks. That's definitely the answer, but ended up not being my real problem of course. I'll accept this and edit my post so it only contains the relevant stuff